# 1GB pages and Transparent Huge Pages (Linux)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tlb, huge-pages

The *Transparent Huge Pages(THP)* support in recent Linux kernels allows automatic promotion/demotion between different page sizes (e.g., 4KB and 2MB in x86-64).

But I am not sure if THP can also promote/demote page sizes between 4KB and 1GB pages or between 2MB and 1GB pages.

Can somebody comment on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this article

http://lwn.net/Articles/423584/

> The current patch only works with anonymous pages; the work to
>   integrate huge pages with the page cache has not yet been done. It
>   also only handles one huge page size (2MB). Even so, some useful
>   performance improvements can be seen. Mel Gorman ran some benchmarks
>   showing improvements of up to 10% or so in some situations. In
>   general, the results were not as good as could be obtained with
>   hugetlbfs, but THP is much more likely to actually be used.

So, it seems that THP support implemented for 4k -> 2M/4M merging/splitting.

Also, in kernel sources I've seen that there is a [split_huge_page_pmd](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.2/include/linux/huge_mm.h#L96) function and as `PMD` undergoes to splitting and `PMD` manages page entries on top of `PTE's` that has a fixed 4k size I supposed that `PMD` size (2M/4M) is the maximum transparent huge page size.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful.

As follow up question: Do you know if this is a fundamental constraint or a temporary one?

Comment: I don't know the details on x86_64 huge page support, but I do know that other platforms have different sizes available.  For instance, IBM power does 64KB and 16GB, and I think some others.

Comment: So, even if hardware supports 1GB pages, THP only works with 2MB/4MB?

Comment: No, THP works with the page sizes supported by the hardware.